# Why $e_1A=M_1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let A be a ring with identity $1$ and $M_1, M_2$ submodules of $A$. We have $1=e_1+e_2$, where $e_i\in M_i$, $i=1, 2$. We can show that $e_i$ are idempotent and $e_1e_2 = e_2e_1 = 0$. We have $e_1A=e_1M_1+e_1M_2=e_1M_1$ since $M_1, M_2$ are submodules of $A$. It is said that $e_1A=M_1$. Then we have to show that $e_1M_1=M_1$. It is clear that $e_1M_1 \subseteq M_1$. But how to show that $M_1 \subseteq e_1M_1$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are speaking of a ring with identity $A$, and $M_1, M_2$ are two right ideals such that $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{ 0 \}$ and $M_1 + M_2 = A$. (They are also submodules if you regard $A$ as a right module over itself.)

To answer your question, an element of $M_1$ is of the form $m =e_1 a$, for $a \in A$, Now $$m = e_1 a = e_1^2 a = e_1 (e_1 a) = e_1 m \in e_1 M_1.$$

Comment: thank you very much. But we don't know that an element of $M_1$ is of the form $m=e_1a$. We have to prove this.

Comment: If $m \in M_1$, then $m = 1 m = (e_1 + e_2) m = e_1 m + e_2 m$. Now $m - e_1 m = e_2 m \in M_1 \cap M_2 = \{ 0 \}$ (an assumption you did not state, but which must be there), so $e_2 m = 0$, and $m = e_1 m$.